# Adding more folders to the Source - Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have problem with adding many folders to Source in Power Query. In company we are using one big Excel file as database but if anyone of us is modifying something in this file everyone of us has to change all the paths in Power Query editor. Is there a way to add multiple paths in Source? We were trying with OR statement or filtering folders but it doesn't work :(

The line for which we need that looks like that:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\my_account\OneDrive\Desktop\RI calculator\Inventory")
```

We were trying to do something like

```
Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\my_account\OneDrive\Desktop\RI calculator\Inventory" OR "C:\Users\colleague_account\Desktop\RI calculator\Inventory")
```

but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how to add more paths to the source? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That way it wouldn't work because you can't just modify the arguments of Folder.Files(). I have never tried that, but maybe there is a way using try otherwise.
Example: "try <some code here that may result in an error> otherwise  <run this code in case of error>"

Comment: I am trying to do it this way: ```Source = try Folder.Files("C:\Users\my_account\OneDrive\Desktop\RI calculator\Inventory") otherwise Folder.Files("C:\Users\colleague_account\Desktop\RI calculator\Inventory")```  and it works but if i put folders in reversed order like first folder is colleague folder and then mine I am receiving an error that it couldn't find folder. Looks like error handling is not very well implemented here or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: That's odd, I don't really know. Let's see if anyone with greater knowledge will give you a hand here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set up the source directory as a variable referencing an excel cell that you can change?

If  you had a cell range named **Directory**, pull it in the query with

```
let Source = Folder.Files(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Directory"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```